# Can I change the code in openzeppelin library in the node modules?

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin, truffle-deployment, openzeppelin-contracts

I am doing nft platform like opensea using openzeppelin. There are some limitations in openzeppelin like only the owner can send the token to anyone. I don't want to use approve function. If I comment the require() function in openzeppelin at the node modules, It worked. My doubt is, Will the change reflect when deploying? or Not....

Answer (score 0):

`node_modules` is for installed libraries and developing code there is not going to do your any good.

You need to learn how properly

- Create your own JavaScript project
- Manage NPM based dependencies
- Extend smart contracts from other projects

Most of this is not relevant to Ethereum, but how to become a JavaScript developer.